# Unknown objectclass inetadmin when trying to create user in opendj through openam

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj, forgerock, directory-server

I am following the official documentation of openam and I am using OpenDJ 2.6.0 and OpenAM 12.0.0:

While executing this api through cmd and postman both:

```
curl \  --request POST \  --header "iplanetDirectoryPro: AQIC5w...2NzEz*" \  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \  --data \  '{    "username": "dummyName",    "userpassword": "secret12",    "mail": "dummyName@example.com"  }' \  http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/json/users/?_action=create
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"code":400,"reason":"Bad Request","message":"Resource cannot be created: Plug-in org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo encountered a ldap exception.  ldap errorcode=65"}
```

While going through access logs of opendj, I can see this error:

```
message="Entry uid=dummyName,dc=example,dc=com violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it contains an unknown objectclass inetadmin" etime=6
```

I searched for objectclass inetadmin, but cant find any class, so that I can create it manually in Opendj.

Answer (score 1):

The schema required for OpenAM must be added to the OpenDJ instance first. There are scripts in OpenAM to do so.

Comment: Hey, can you give reference for the scripts which need to be added in OpenDJ